# Model Join calculus as hypergraphs

Tags: graphs, concurrency, computation-models

I'm not sure if this is the right site to ask, but I couldn't find a another one.

Some time ago I found out about the [join calculus](http://join.inria.fr/). It is based on constructs called joins to support concurrency. For example: (pseudocode)

```
int get() & void set(x) {
    return x to get
}

void main() {
    set(1)
  & set(2)
  & print(get())
}
```

would randomly output 1 or 2.

Yesterday I learned about hypergraph rewriting as a programming model. [LMNtal](http://www.ueda.info.waseda.ac.jp/lmntal/) for example.

My question is whether every join can be expressed as a hypergraph. The pseudocode from above would for example transform into:

[image: Joins as hypergraph]

Comment: @Raphael Ok done, but I'm starting to think I'm asking the wrong question. I was thinking about a language where both code and data are modeled as hyper-graphs, some kind of everything-is-a-hypergraph, like pythons everything-is-an-object. This would also make meta-programming easy to implement.

Comment: Thanks, the image is clearer now. I'm not sure what you are getting at (can't infer rules from your example), but that may be a problem on my end.

Comment: @Raphael I'm not entirely sure myself anymore. The problem is that I had no rules in mind. But if every hypergraph rewriting rule can be rewritten as a hypergraph by putting a directed edge between the left -and right hand side, then a hypergraph would be able to express turing complete systems. And since the join calculus is turing complete, every program in the join calculus would be able to be rewritten as a hypergraph. Is that a valid proof?